# PyCharm replaced a python file with an XML file, how do I get it back?

Tags: pycharm

I was using Pycharm, and I switched from `gae_models_test.py` to `exp_services_test.py`, a file in a project I'm working on. Then, my laptop battery died.

When I started my laptop, and PyCharm back up, it opened up `gae_models_test.py`. So, I switched back to `exp_services_test.py`, but when I opened it, I found a huge blob of XML that definitely isn't the Python code I was working on. How do I get my code back, and how do I prevent things like this to happen in the future?

**EDIT:** The file on disk is not affected, but when I reopen the project, the XML is still there. Is there a way to tell pycharm to get the actual contents of the file?

I've also tried invalidating the cache, but that didn't work.

**EDIT 2** So I removed the .idea directory, restarted pycharm, and opened the project directory using the 'open directory' option on the startup screen, and guess what, now the file on disk is XML! I have backups, so I can put things right, but **THIS SHOULD NEVER HAPPEN, APPLICATIONS SHOULD CONSIDER FILES ON DISK AS THEIR SOURCE OF TRUTH!** I relly like PyCharm, and I've never found a Python IDE that works as well for me, but destroying people's files is not good practice.

[image: bunch of xml]

Comment: did you have it in source control?

Comment: Yes, I did. But I noticed the file on disk is unaffected so there must be a way to tell PyCharm to display the actual contents.

Comment: seems like an interesting bug

Comment: Have you tried to restore it using VCS | Local History?

Comment: I've restored it using VCS.

Comment: File -> Invalidate Caches should probably help in this case.

Comment: Unfortunately I can confirm this bug. My computer's battery ran out while I was editing a file. When I opened PyCharm again, the file was missing in the project explorer even though it still existed in the directory. And in the directory, the file was completely empty. -- PyCharm does have the old content in its history, though. I am currently trying to figure out how to restore that.